# Question on counting the number of triangles formed by 1999 points in a square

Tags: geometry, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle, tessellations

I was reading an explanation for a solution to an Olympiad problem as follows:
Let $S$ be a square with the side length 20 and let $M$ be the set of points formed with the vertices of $S$ and another 1999 points lying inside $S$. Prove that there exists a triangle with vertices in $M$ and with area at most equal with $\frac 1{10}$.

In the solution it states that if you want to cover the square S with triangles formed by the points in M and the vertices of S, you will need 4000 triangles for which this calculation is provided: 2 * (1999 + 1) = 4000. How was this figure obtained/what is the explanation behind this calculation?

Comment: This follows from the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Plane_graphs) of a triangulation with these points as vertices.

Comment: You need three equations in three unknowns: as well as the Euler characteristic, also use that each triangle has three edges and each edge is an edge of two triangles  (apart from the four edges of the original square), and that you know the number of vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a much simpler verification, double count the angle sum.

Consider all of the vertex angles of the triangles. What is their sum?

- Each triangle has an angle sum of $180^\circ$.
- The 1999 points each contribute $360^\circ$ (Why?). Add in the 4 corners which have total of $360^\circ$.
- Hence, there are a total of $ \frac { (1999+1) \times 360^\circ } { 180^\circ} = 4000$ triangles.

Answer (score 2):

[The Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler%27s_formula) tells that $v-e+f=2$, where $v$ is the number of vertices, $e$ is the number of edges, $f$ is the number of faces (including the outer infinite face). We know that $$v=4+1999=2003.$$

Let us calculate $e$. Each triangle face has $3$ edges surrounding it. The outer face has $4$ edges. It would give $3(f-1)+4$ edges. But every edge is counted twice here, since every edge splits two faces. So, $$e= \frac{3(f-1)+4}2.$$

Put it into the Euler’s formula: $$2003-\frac{3(f-1)+4}2+f=2$$

$$4006-3f+3-4+2f=4$$

$$f=4001.$$

So the number of triangles is $f-1=4000.$

Comment: Surely it should be 4006 instead of 2006?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I fixed it